# Inequality with continued fractions: $\theta_r \geq a_{r+2}\theta_{r+1} + \theta_{r+1}$

Tags: inequality, continued-fractions

I want to prove that the following inequality is true (or that is false, I don not know but I think it is true).
$$\theta_r \geq a_{r+2}\theta_{r+1} + \theta_{r+1}.$$
Here the notation is as follow:
$\alpha$ is a positive irrational number. The continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$ is 
$$\alpha = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots].$$
In other words 
\begin{equation*}
\alpha = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \ldots}}.
\end{equation*}
We denote with $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ the irreducible fraction representing the $i$-th convergent of $\alpha$.
Finally $\theta_n$ is defined as follows $$\theta_n = \vert q_n\alpha - p_n\vert.$$
Additional details: we suppose $r \geq 2$. 
If the inequality is false, which is the first integer $k$ for which the following weaker inequality holds?
$$\theta_r \geq a_{r+2}\theta_{r+1} + \theta_{r+k+1}.$$

Comment: suggest you do experiments with random real numbers on computer, one would expect to get correct $a_n$ for, say, $n <10$ using ordinary computer doubles.

Comment: Rudely simulposted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/181961/inequality-with-continued-fractions-theta-r-geq-a-r2-theta-r1-theta without informing either site of the post at the other.

Comment: Sorry, the next time I will wait more before to post it also  in MO, and I will link the question in MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opposite inequality is true.  Since $p_n=a_np_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$ and $q_n=a_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}$, we have
$$
p_n-\alpha q_n = a_n(p_{n-1}-\alpha q_{n-1}) + (p_{n-2}-\alpha q_{n-2}).
$$
Since consecutive convergents alternate sides around $\alpha$, it follows that
$$
\theta_n=-a_n\theta_{n-1}+\theta_{n-2}.
$$
Finally, since the $\theta_n$'s are nonnegative and decreasing, we have
$$
a_n\theta_{n-1}\le\theta_{n-2}<(a_n+1)\theta_{n-1}.
$$
Hence the stated inequality is always false, and the modified inequality at the end of the question is actually an equality for $k=1$, and a strict inequality for $k>1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! The question has originate from this article:
Thank you! I cite the article where I found this inequality:
J.-M. Deshouullers A. B ́ıro ́ and V. T. So ́s. Good approximation and cha- racterization of subgroups of R/Z. Studia Scientiarum Mathematicarum Hungarica, 38:105–110, 2001. Pag.108.